# Break import cycle while type checking

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, pytype

I have split a large class implementation into different packages [1], and have used an import inside a method body to avoid a compilation cycle, as follows:

```
# model.py

class MyInt:
  def __init__(self, value: int):
    self.value = value

  def is_prime(self) -> bool:
    from methods import is_prime
    return is_prime(self)
```

```
# methods.py

from model import MyInt

def is_prime(x: MyInt) -> bool:
  # TODO: actually implement this
  return x.value == 2 or x.value % 2 == 1
```

However, pytype is not happy about this, failing to find the pyi file when reaching the import cycle:

> File "/home/bkim/Projects/mwe/model.py", line 6, in is_prime: Couldn't import pyi for 'methods' [pyi-error]
>
> Can't find pyi for 'model', referenced from 'methods'

How can I avoid this and still get type-checking?

[1] I've done this with just one tiny, utility method, actually. No need to yell about splitting a class across multiple packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses `typing.TYPE_CHECKING`, to have one behavior during type checking and another during runtime:

```
import typing

class MyInt:
  def is_prime(self) -> bool:
    if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
      return False  
    from methods import is_prime
    return is_prime(self)
```

Curiously, using `from typing import TYPE_CHECKING` doesn't work, which may be a bug?

Comment: Could also be useful: https://github.com/google/pytype/issues/428#issuecomment-538151912